# When should endfile be used, before or after reading?

Tags: vhdl

While looking for examples of reading text from a file (using `readline` and `read`), I constantly see code like the following, but haven't found information on what exactly `endfile` does.

```
while not endfile(in_file) loop
    readline(in_file, in_line);
    read(in_line, in_data);
end loop;
```

In all other languages I know, end of file would be checked *after* reading the line from the file, not before.

What exactly are the semantics of `endfile` that make this usage correct?

Comment: Empty files, for a start.

Comment: @BrianDrummond In other languages, I would normally just try to read the data from the file, and break out of the loop if the read fails (which would also catch empty files). VHDL is the only language I know of where you first check if the read would fail due to end of file, and only if not actually perform the read.

Comment: Also from the same section as your answer from reading the LRM - "An error will occur when a READ operation is performed on file F if ENDFILE(F) would return TRUE at that point".  Errors cause simulation to cease. Notice it prevents buffer overruns.

Answer (score 1):

From the IEEE VHDL Standard:

> 3.4.1 File operations ... Function ENDFILE returns FALSE
>   if a subsequent READ operation on an open ﬁle object whose access mode is read-only can retrieve another value from the ﬁle; otherwise, it returns TRUE.

So checking `endfile` prior to reading from the file is correct, since `endfile` returns `false` as long as another value/line can be read.

Answer (score 0):

There are several languages which use an eof function or statement to determine the end of a file. These languages or library have no special return value (-1, null, nil, ...) or even a exception mechanism to report a failed read(..), so in this case its necessary to test eof before a read(..) and proof that one more read(..) won't crash the program.

### Edit 1

zennehoy asked for some language examples, which use this kind of EOF statement/function:

Example 1: QBasic

```
open "file.txt" for input as #1
do until eof(1)
  input #1,name$,street$, ...
loop
close #1
```

Example 2: Windows Scripting Host (WSH), alias VBA, alias VB Script:

```
do until fileHandle.atEndOfStream
  [...]
loop
```

Example 3: if I remember correctly this would be Pascal

Ansi-C has also a eof functionality, but in many cases its not necessary to use it, because you can determine the end of a file, if read(..) returns less bytes than the requested bytes.

**But** this won't function if you are reading from streams/pipes/... because read can return less bytes and after several milliseconds there are more bytes and you can read again. A test for EOF will assure you, that a writer on a stream is closed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other languages do you know that have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Another example language where the end of file status is tested first is [Ada](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Input_loop#Ada) as in `while not End_Of_File loop`, where `End_Of_File` is a function in package [Ada.Text_IO](https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/rts/a-textio__ads.htm#51_13) and the default value for it's single argument of type File_Mode is `In_file`.  As of Ada95, `End_Of_File` only operates on files of mode `In_File` or `Inout_File` otherwise generating an exception. (While `endfile` will return FALSE for WRITE_MODE in VHDL).

Early implementations of VHDL included preprocessors for Ada in the days of big iron.  You can see the influence throughout the LRM.  For instance there is no coupling between bit positions and integer values or description of a float format.  These happen to allow VHDL to operate on a computer with native decimal ALUs.